# Binary Search Tree node deletion error

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've created my binary search tree and gave the pointer to the node which I want to delete into my `*p`.

The delete method is supposed to be deleting the node which is pointed at by `*p` and should add the subtrees with `addtree` to my root.  `*pBaum` is the pointer which points to my root.

However im getting an error message called "conflict types" on `addtree` everytime I declare

```
Baum = addtree(Baum, p->right);
```

I also get a warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

My struct contains left & right pointer to the subtrees and a pointer to the content.

```
struct tnode
{
int content;
struct tnode *left; /* linker Teilbaum */
struct tnode *right; /* rechter Teilbaum */
};

// Deletes the node where *p is pointing at

struct tnode  *deletenode(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pBaum)
{
   struct tnode *Baum = pBaum;

    if ((p->left == NULL) && (p->right == NULL))
    {
      free(p);
    }
    if ((p->left == NULL) && (p->right != NULL))
    {
      Baum = addtree(Baum, p->right);
      free(p);

    }
    if ((p->right == NULL) && (p->left !=NULL))
    {
      Baum = addtree(Baum, p->left);
      free(p);
    }
    if ((p->left != NULL) && (p->right !=NULL))
    {
      Baum = addtree(Baum, p->right);
      Baum = addtree(Baum, p->left);
      free(p);
    }
  return Baum;
}

// Adds the Subtrees to my root

struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p)
{
if (p == NULL)
    return top;
else
return addtree(addtree(addelement(top, p->content),p-> right),   p->left);

// Adds a node to my Tree

struct tnode *addelement(struct tnode *p, int i)
{
int cond;
if (p == NULL)
{
    p = talloc(); /* make a new node */ p->content = i;
    p->left =p->right =NULL;
}
else if (p->content == i)
{
    return p;
}
else if (i < p->content) /* goes into left subtree */ p->left =addelement(p->left, i);
else /* goes into right subtree */ p->right = addelement(p->right, i);
return p;
}

// Looks for the node which is supposed to get deleted and returns a pointer to it 

struct tnode *searchnode(struct tnode *p, int nodtodelete)
{
if (p == NULL)
{
    printf("Baum ist leer oder Element nicht vorhanden \n");
    return NULL;
}
if ( p -> content == nodtodelete)
{
    return p;
}
if (p->content < nodtodelete)
{
    return searchnode (p->right, nodtodelete);
}
if (p->content > nodtodelete)
{
    return searchnode(p->left, nodtodelete);
}
}
}

int main()
{
struct tnode *Baum = NULL;
struct tnode *tmpPos = NULL;
Baum = addelement (Baum, 32);
Baum = addelement(Baum, 50);
Baum = addelement(Baum, 60);
tmpPos = searchnode(Baum,50);
Baum = deletenode(tmpPos, Baum);
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: error: conflicting types for 'addtree'

Comment: No, the full error message, including filename and line number and the rest of the error.

Comment: Read [ask], organize your code, and be more specific about the problem

Comment: is supposed to be C and : 
Binary_Search_Tree.c|120|error: conflicting types for 'addtree'|

Comment: @RobinSchmidt That looks incomplete. Isn't there more?

Comment: there is didnt want to post the whole code. I can if you want to

Comment: I think I see one of the problems: You're calling `addtree` before it's defined.

Comment: You need to declare `struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p);` before `struct tnode  *deletenode(struct tnode *p, struct tnode *pBaum)
{//...`

Comment: @RobinSchmidt _"there is didnt want to post the whole code. I can if you want to"_ No, prepare a [MCVE] instead, showing the behavior/error in question.

Comment: What is the defintion of struct tnode? Though not directly related to your question, you might want to check out this code:

    tmpPos = searchnode(Baum,50);
    Baum = deletenode(tmpPos, Baum);
 
searchnode() can return NULL and within deletenode(), there is the possibility of dereferencing a NULL pointer; your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare the function before function call in code ? i declare the addtree and addelement functions on top of the file and error for conflict types is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is due to you only including partial code, but you addtree function is not complete:

```
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p)
{
if (p == NULL)
    return top;
else
return addtree(addtree(addelement(top, p->content),p-> right),   p->left);
```

This function needs to be ended with a bracket:

```
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p)
{
    if(p == NULL)
        return top;
    return addtree(addtree(addelement(top, p->content), p->right), p->left);
}
```

To make it so the compiler doesn't potentially complain about not returning a value in a non void function it's best to get rid of the else as well.